# How do I call getDuration in mediaBrowserService from an Activity?

Tags: android-service, android-mediaplayer, android-seekbar, android-mediasession, mediabrowserservice

Earlier, using boundService this could be easily achieved. But with MediaBrowserService I can't access getDuration outside, without which I am unable to update the seekbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the MediaBrowserService, when you're updating the MediaMetadata, add the duration of the current media.

```
MediaMetadataCompat.Builder metadataBuilder = new MediaMetadataCompat.Builder();
metadataBuilder.putLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION, track.durationMs);
```

While on the client side, using MediaBrowserCompat you're able to connect to you MediaBrowserService and retrieve a MediaSessionCompat.Token. With the token you can then get a MediaSessionController from where you can get the [MediaMetadataCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaControllerCompat.html#getMetadata()) that has information about the current media.

```
int duration = (int) metadata.getLong(MediaMetadataCompat.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
```

The official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowser-client.html) has an *ok* explanation on how this works a whole

Comment: I had found out alrdy....bt i stoped app dev...so didnt bother about answering myself  nywys...tnx man.